# How to start a task when there is no keyboard or mouse input on Windows?

Tags: windows-7

I'm using Windows 7, and I want to start a task via task scheduler when there is no keyboard or mouse input.

I know how to start a task when computer is idle, for example, the following command setup a task when idle,

```
SCHTASKS /Create /F /TN "task_name" /RU "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /SC ONIDLE /I 2 /TR "C:\path\to\task.exe parameters"
```

`ONIDLE` means:

> Task Scheduler checks for an idle state using two criteria: user
>   absence, and a lack of resource consumption. The user is considered
>   absent if there is no keyboard or mouse input during this period of
>   time. The computer is considered idle if all the processors and all
>   the disks were idle for more than 90% of the last detection interval.

Quoted from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383561(v=vs.85).aspx

But now I want to launch a task only based on one condition: user absence, i.e.,  there is no keyboard or mouse input.

Anybody knows how to do this? Thanks

Comment: Soulmachine - The Scheduled Task `Trigger` property can be set for begin the task "on idle" and you can also use the `Condition` tab if a job you are scheduling to give it further conditions to meet before executed and one is `Start the task only if the computer is idle for <x time period>`  and `Wait for idle for <x time period>`.  Begin task "on idle" should do exactly what you are suggesting. Otherwise you can trigger a process to run every x seconds or minutes, etc. and use the `Condition` tab to tell it to only run if the PC have been idle for x amount of time and if not then ............

Comment: .... wait x amount of time before ending in case the first condition becomes true before the wait time expires so it'll quit and wait for the next trigger. You are missing some details I think. Can this process run many times a day so if the PC is idle for 32 hours straight, is the task expected to run once a minute forever while idle or only once when idle per day or what. I think what you are asking is possible but I need to understand this process you are running a bit and how often it can run or you expect it to run if or once idle, and so forth.

Comment: What I need is  the condition, `ONIDLE` just means running a  task when computer is idle, while what I need is that running a task when user has no activity such as key stroke or mouse movement

Comment: When there is no activity (including user mouse and key strokes) how long of a time period do you need to lapse when this condition becomes true before your task is run? Once the task is run and then if the machine is still not active (no end-user anything) then is this process supposed to run again after that or just once per each inactive period? Can you tell me what this task does that runs once the activity is inactive or whatever to give me an idea of what you're doing? I've had to automate many things so I'd be surprised if there's anything that surprises me with this task.

Answer (score 0):

Idle condition in Windows Task Scheduler includes CPU or memory usage in addition to keyboard or mouse input, so it cannot be your solution. I believe nncron can solve this problem.